# GWT Dynamic String Internationalization example

Tags: gwt, internationalization

Can anyone post a complete example or point me to the location of GWT Dynamic String Internationalization.

I cant find it anywhere online. All i can find is static String Internationalization.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n.html#DevGuideDynamicStringInternationalization) is it, on the online documentation. And [here](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDictionaryExample) it is the showcase sample.

Comment: This example is a non-example. Or I don't understand it.